# no default constructor exists for class x (inheritance) C++

Tags: c++

I have the following three headers:

**IBaseStates.h**

```
class IBaseStates
{
public:
    enum STATE;

    virtual void Update( STATE state ) = 0;
};
```

**PlayerStates.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "IBaseStates.h"
#include "Player.h"

class PlayerStates : public IBaseStates, public Player
{
public:
    enum STATE {
        FLYING,
        FALLING
    };

    int textureAmount;

    PlayerStates();
    ~PlayerStates( );

    void Update( STATE state );
};
```

**Player.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "StructVertex.h"
#include "SquareVertices.h"
#include "WICTextureLoader.h"

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace DirectX;
//using namespace DirectX;

class Player : public SquareVertices
{
public:
    Player( ComPtr<ID3D11Device1> d3dDevice );
    ~Player();

    void Initialize();
    void Update();

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float rotation;
    float velocity;

    ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> vertexbuffer;
    ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> indexbuffer;
    ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView> texture[3];
protected:
    const ComPtr<ID3D11Device1> d3dDevice;
};
```

Why when I define a constructor for my PlayerStates class in my PlayerStates.cpp file do I get

```
no default constructor exists for class Player
```

**PlayerStates.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "PlayerStates.h"

PlayerStates::PlayerStates()
: 
    textureAmount( 3 )
{
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to declare the destructor of child class as virtual.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you declare a non-default constructor for a class, the compiler does not generate a default one anymore. So you have to provide your own.

`PlayerStates` needs to call a default constructor of its base class `Player` in its own default constructor. So you either need to provide `Player` with a default constructor, or call it's non-default constructor from `PlayerStates`' default constructor initialization list.

This implicitly calls `Player::Player()`.

```
PlayerStates::PlayerStates() : textureAmount( 3 ) {}
```

This calls the single argument constructor:

```
PlayerStates::PlayerStates() : Player(someComPtr), textureAmount( 3 ) {}
```

Comment: I have declared a cpp version of a Player constructor... is that what you mean?

Comment: You declared one that takes an argument, but that doesn't help in this case (since you don't have a d3dDevice in your PlayerStates constructor).

Comment: @JamesT no, you need to give `Player` a default constructor.

Comment: A default constructor is one without arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`Player` can't be created with out a `ComPtr<ID3D11Device1> d3dDevice`, so you're `PlayerStates` constructor is going to have to find one and pass it to `Player`.

```
PlayerStates::PlayerStates()
: 
  Player( globalD3DDevice ),
  textureAmount( 3 )
{
}
```

Or, if that's not what you intended, turn the inheritance around like you mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I know I deleted my comment before, but going off of the same basis as that... d3dDevice that I want to be kept inside Players' belly is no longer accessible by PlayerStates... even if I make PlayerStates a friend of Player... Maybe the other way round was correct?

Comment: Does `PlayerStates` need access to the `ID3D11Device1` ?

Comment: Yes indeedy. I want the PlayerStates to have access to the Device so that I can load textures... the texture loading function requires a pointer to the device... I'm doing this inheritance to organize the code better... what do you think?

Comment: You know what, don't worry.. I'll just sort something else out, thanks for your help dude